# Segfault whilst reading message

Tags: ros, husky, joint-states

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi we've been writting some code to subscribe to the /joint_states topic produced by the husky simulator.
However we found that even though all the arrays in /joint_states should be the same length, we are getting an empty array for velocity at random intervals. Which causes a seg fault as there appears to be no way to detect it. (checking if msg->velocity == NULL won't compile).
So two questions, is there a way to stop these invalid messages? And if there isn't what is the best way to detect the empty array (gdb says its a boost shared vector).

Thanks,
Harry

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/154991/segfault-whilst-reading-message/) by [hjed](https://answers.ros.org/users/13326/hjed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The arrays of Float64 data in [sensor_msgs/JointState](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/JointState.html)  are represented by a `std::vector<double>` when using roscpp. You should thus be able to get the length of the vector by calling `YOUR_MSG.velocity.size()`.

The "velocity disappearance" issue sounds like a bug to me, but maybe some other husky user or dev can comment on that one.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hjed](https://answers.ros.org/users/13326/hjed/) on 2014-04-19**:
Thanks, this is a very good fix for the problem